# Which of the following operation can lead to illegal memory access

Tags: c, pointers

Consider the following declaration of C code.

```
int (*p)[10];
```

If the variable is not initialized to any address then which of the following may give a run-time error?

1. `(p+1)`
2. `(p+1)[2]`
3. `p[2]`
4. `*p[2]`

My answer: 2, 3, 4.

As p is not initialized it can contain any garbage value, so
`*(p+3)`, `*(p+2)`, and `**(p+2)` can lead to illegal memory access.

Given answer: 4.

Their explanation:
We get a runtime error (segmentation fault) if we try to access some invalid memory.
is a pointer to an integer array of size Its declaration has one * (star) and one [ ] (square bracket). If we want to access memory using  then we have to use
Either two * (stars)
Or  one * (star) and one [ ] (square bracket)
Or  two  [ ] (square bracket)

Following usages might give runtime errors -

```
**p
*p[]
p[][]
```

can 2 and 3 lead to illegal memory accesses?

Comment: Note that going out of bounds or otherwise using a pointer wrongly, it will lead to *undefined behavior*. It *might* cause a "run-time error" or a crash, or it might not.

Comment: As for the 1-4 list of expressions, they are *all* wrong in one way or another.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  I think p+1 is fine. nothing wrong with it. as p is any garbage value p + 1 is also some garbage value + 1. I mean p + 1 will not cause an illegal memory access or crash.

Comment: While `1` doesn't dereference the pointer, it's result is a pointer that is incorrect. So I would still consider it incorrect.

Comment: which does not lead to any error.

Comment: Just because something doesn't make your program crash, it could still be wrong. And that goes for *all* the alternatives: They will result in *undefined behavior* but might not result in a crash. (Well, except `1` since the pointer isn't dereferenced, but it's not a correct pointer either way and having it in code is bad)

Comment: the first one can only be used rvalue and if used in the expression or assigned it can lead to UB

Comment: @0___________ pointer addition is UB if the pointer isn't valid (or if the result isn't in an array or just after the last thing in an array), so 1 is also UB

Comment: @PaulHankin any access past array is UB. You can only use one past last element in pointer arithmetics.

Comment: Yes, but my point was that invalid pointer arithmetic is UB whether or not you dereference the pointer.

Comment: @PaulHankin indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally none and all of them. Everything depends on how you use it.

Exmaples:

1. If you use it in `sizeof` it is safe

```
    printf("%zu\n",sizeof((p+1)));
    printf("%zu\n",sizeof(((p+1)[2])));
    printf("%zu\n",sizeof((p[2])));
    printf("%zu\n",sizeof((*p[2])));
```

2.Any of them can lead to the Undefined Behaviour (which can express itself as memory fault)

```
    p = (p+1);  //UB is p is dereferenced
    int *x = (p+1)[2]; //x has undermined value
    int *y = p[2];     //same as above
    *p[2] = 5;         //p was not initialized
```

Comment: Maybe this is a very silly doubt, but when (p+1)[2] gets evaluated do we access the memory address (p+3) to get the value of x?

Comment: All are undefined behsviours if your teacher says something else he is wrong

Comment: yes, but as this is a test question and it asks for runtime errors and I am arguing 2 can lead to a runtime error, it would be helpful to know that whether it can lead to a runtime error.

Comment: @KhushitShah you need to understand that run-time error is not the same as UB. UBs may or may not express themself as run-time errors. The same UB can or not result in RT error even on the same machine. Your teacher does not understand the problem and is teaching you incorrectly. He can only ask what is UB, not wat will result in RT error as it is not possible to predict.